# Add custom notification or message in a Microsoft Teams chat

Tags: notifications, message, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams, custom-notification

Hi on behalf of the company I work for, I am trying to implement something in addition to the current Microsoft Teams information (status, banners, etc.) that displays information from an external source. Specifically, our goal would be to show (inside the single chats or externally inside the info banners of the single users) if a user is in the office or in smartworking. This information will be taken from an external source, in particular from a database that manages presences. Is there a way to be able to show within Microsoft Teams (via a custom field, status message or other) the information retrieved for each individual user as to whether or not they are in the office?
I've tried using the Microsoft Graph API but none of them proved useful in achieving the goal. I wanted to know if it was possible to achieve such a result using other libraries or something else.
Any advice is welcome, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Currently it is not possible to set status message in teams.

We recommend you to raise a Teams UserVoice [here](https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/) if this needs to be considered as a future request.